# An error occured while communicating to the server

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery-jtable

Im using jTable in my code in jquery modile, I get parameter from query string and bind to jtable, but im getting error:An error occured while communicating to the server.

here is my code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {
                $('#ResultContainer').jtable({
                    title: 'Search List',
                    paging: true, //Enables paging
                    pageSize: 10, //Actually this is not needed since default value is 10.
                    sorting: true, //Enables sorting
                    actions: {
                        listAction: "SearchResult.aspx/GetSearch"

                    },
                    fields: {
                        Ref: {
                            title: "Ref",
                            width: '30%'
                        },
                        Trademark: {
                            title: 'Trademark',
                            width: '30%'
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('#ResultContainer').jtable('load', {
                    org: '<%= Request["org"] %> ',
                    catchword: ('<%= Request["tm"] %> ')
                });
            });
```

my webmethod is

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static object GetSearch(string org, string catchword, int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)
{
    List<Coverage> tm = new List<Coverage>();
    try
    {
        //Get data from database
        using (ORepository repository = new ORepository())
        {
            tm = repository.getCoveragebyTM(catchword, org,0,10,"catchword");
            int cnt = tm.Count;
            return new { Result = "OK", Records = tm, TotalRecordCount = cnt };
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
    }
}
```

Anybody could please help me. How to call    `$('#ResultContainer').jtable('load', {..`
on pageload?

Edit:

Im getting this message inn Response
{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027org\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: Probably that the path to :  listAction: "SearchResult.aspx/GetSearch" is incorrect, check that.

Comment: i checked that with help of ajax call and it is working   function Getdata() {
                    var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/SearchResult.aspx")%>'
                    var DTO = "{org: '" + ('<%= Request["org"] %> ') + "',catchword: '" + ('<%= Request["tm"] %> ') + "'}";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: pageUrl + "/GetSearch",

Comment: Based on your error message you're not passing a value through properly.

Comment: I suspect that calling function is somehow wrong , but im calling it mobile page load as im using jquery mobile, im lacking knowlegde there. I want to display grid on pageload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by passing values to jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing any value for org and catchword parameters. You can do it with  listAction: "SearchResult.aspx/GetSearch?org=asd&catchword=asd"

Also, you can check network packages with firebug or chrome dev tools to see error detail.

Comment: solved by passing values to jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JTable execution result, there are two state identification, ok, and others. When the state is! Ok when your message will be reported if a non-digital state this error. Recommended as a state background using digital identification and correction within the source code.

```
            String error="{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"+100+"}";
                    response.getWriter().print(error);
    if (data.Result != 'OK') {
                        if(data.Message == 100){
                            self._showError('未登录！请重新登录');
                        }else{
                            self._showError(data.Message);
                        }
                        //window.location.href="login.jsp";
                        return;
                    }
if (data.Result != 'OK') {
                        if(data.Message == 100){
                            self._showError('未登录！请重新登录');
                        }else{
                            self._showError(data.Message);
                        }
                        //window.location.href="login.jsp";
                        return;
                    }
```